# Using OAuth with twitter and preventing duplicate registration

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, openid

I am implementing OAuth onto my site. I intend to allow someone to sign on with either their Facebook, Google or Twitter accounts as I believe this takes up a massive share of the market.

However while Facebook and Google allow you to receive a user's email address, Twitter does not. This presents a problem for subscribers of multiple services, if someone logs in via Facebook or Google and uses a different method next time I can recognise they are the same user and provide them with their content.

If someone later uses Twitter without some form of unique identifier that matches data received from Facebook or Google I can't see if the user has already signed up and am forced to present the user with an entirely new account and not allow them access to data they may have already accrued.

Is it possible to recognise whether someone has previously authorised access to your site through Facebook or Google when they log in via Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way. The way i implement it is give the user the ability to add more services once they have registred with one. Mostly because a user can register their account on facebook, twitter and google with different email addresses.

Unfortunately i have... And I would want to be able to link all my services to the same account even if i don´t have the same email on all of them.